# Android setOnClickListener with 2 functions

Tags: android

Im "playing" with Android Studio, making a DrumPad app, but im struggling with it. I want that my buttons, if clicked, start playing the sample and if clicked again, just stop the sample. Every button have differents MediaPlayers, so here is an example of what im trying to do:

```
redbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chord1_ashp_maj7);
            mediaplayer.start();
        }
        stopPlaying(mediaplayer);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 5):

just put else part ..

like,

```
if (!mediaplayer.isPlaying())
{
   mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chord1_ashp_maj7);
   mediaplayer.start();
}
else
{
    stopPlaying(mediaplayer);
}
```

Because, you have to stop media player if its already running..

**Note:** Yeah I know, may be you have taken care of it in `stopPlaying()` function but without code of this function I assumed you have to put stop media player part in else statement.

Comment: @Paulo Ferreira- your if condition should be, `if(mediaplayer == null || !mediaplayer.isPlaying())`

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand you very clearly, it is just a case of 
if(---condition--){--statement--}else{--statement--} issue

```
redbutton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!mediaplayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chord1_ashp_maj7);
            mediaplayer.start();
        }else{
        stopPlaying(mediaplayer);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried that, but when I click the button, it just close the app, and without the else, runs perfectly, but only repeat the sound. by the way, the stopPlaying code is if (m != null) { m.stop(); m.release(); m = null; }

Comment: What is the stackTrace? @PauloFerreira

Comment: what do you mean with stackTrace?

Comment: Didn't saw, but i resolved the problem.  This is how i solved it:

Comment: if (aredbtn2==false)
                {
                    aredbtn2=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    aredbtn2=false;
                }

                if(aredbtn2 == true)
                {
                        mredbutton2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chord1_ashp_maj7);
                        mredbutton2.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    stopPlaying(mredbutton2);
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (aredbtn2==false) 
    { 
        aredbtn2=true; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        aredbtn2=false; 
    } 
    if(aredbtn2 == true) 
    { 
        mredbutton2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chord1_ashp_maj7); mredbutton2.start(); } else { stopPlaying(mredbutton2); 
    }
```